# LLVM 3.4 unable to select Platform Toolset in VS 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, llvm

I have built the LLVM using Cmake from the documentation @ [LLVM on visual studio](http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStartedVS.html). I have an **existing code** project in visual studio, where I want to build my interpretor. I want to set the `Platform Toolset` to LLVM, however when I navigate to `Properties>general>Platform` Toolset in VS 2012 for my existing project, I dont see an option to add the LLVM tool chain in the drop down. I must be doing something terribly wrong here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LLVM Platform Toolset is not built by default- it requires a custom installation step and is not as simple as "Just build LLVM". Typically, it's easier to just download the installer from [the LLVM Website](http://llvm.org/builds/). If you want to know how to build the Windows installer yourself, you'll have to ask in #llvm on OFTC.net.

Note that the existing LLVM Platform Toolset solution has some serious integration limits, like no exceptions/RTTI and AFAIK no support for the debugger and such too, which makes it seriously limited. Right now it's mostly useful for getting better error messages.